# Как записать % в ConfigParser Python?

Tags: python

Нужно записать '%7' в конфиг файл, но при попытке сделать это выдаётся ошибка, экранирование через '%%7' не подходит

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()

path = 'config.ini'

config.read(path)
config.set('main', 'mystr', '%7')

with open(path, 'w') as f:
    config.write(f)
```

Comment: Если экранирование через %% не подходит - тогда через configparser не получится. Вообще, не вижу тут проблемы - при записи в конфиг удваиваете процент, при чтении - наоборот заменяете на одинарный.

Comment: И нет ничего типо r'text' ?

Comment: Нет. `r'text'` влияет на то, как Python обрабатывает слеши, а тут ограничения самого configparser, он использует проценты например для подстановки значений из самого конфига, как описано тут: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values . Проще какой-нибудь json или yaml для хранения настроек использовать.

Comment: Это я так для примера привёл. Ладно, буду делать replace('%', '%%')

Comment: @insolor, при экранировании в INI файл записывается `"%%"` вместо `"%"`

Comment: При чтении один %, поэтому мне подходит

Comment: @MaxU, я не утверждал, что будет один записываться. Это единственный способ записать проценты, если они так уж нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если еще актуально, вот так работает.

```
import configparser
from pathlib import Path


config = configparser.ConfigParser()

path = 'config.ini'

config.add_section("main") # Удалить, если секция [main] существует.

config.read(path)
config.set('main', 'mystr', '%%7')

# Открываем, находим, заменяем, сохраняем.
with open(path, 'w') as f:
    config.write(f)

Path('config.ini').write_text(Path('config.ini').read_text().replace('%%7', '%7'))
```

Comment: Path('config.ini').write_text(Path('config.ini').read_text().replace('%%', '%'))